# Spring Boot - Couldn't get at the OracleSpatial Connection object from the PreparedStatement

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, oracle-spatial

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1 , hibernate-spatial 5.2.17 , Oracle DB 12c.
HikariCP For Connection pool and hibernate dialect as OracleSpatial10gDialect. I get the following exception when hibernate spatial functions are used in my query.

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't get at the OracleSpatial Connection object from the PreparedStatement.; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't get at the OracleSpatial Connection object from the PreparedStatement.

I tried suggestions from here [Couldn't get at the OracleSpatial Connection object from the PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753350/couldnt-get-at-the-oraclespatial-connection-object-from-the-preparedstatement) . But facing same issue.

Any pointers to the solution would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

The ConnectionFinder interface

[image]

I solved the problem:

- implementing the interface org.geolatte.geom.codec.db.oracle.ConnectionFinder;

  ```
  public class CustomConnectionFinder implements ConnectionFinder {
     @SneakyThrows
     @Override
     public Connection find(Connection connection) {
       return ((HikariProxyConnection) connection).unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
     }
   }
  ```
- Configuring the application.yml:

```
    spring:
      jpa:
        properties:
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect
            spatial:
              connection_finder: it.dedagroup.slim.data.domain.CustomConnectionFinder
```